# Only else statement is executing

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';    
$dbuser = 'root';    
$dbpass = '';      
$dbname = 'moviefone';    

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('can not connect to the database');  
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

if (!empty($_POST['usernamesignup']) && !empty ($_POST['emailsignup']) && !empty($_POST['passwordsignup'])
&& !empty($_POST['passwordsignup']) && !empty($_POST['passwordsignup_confirm']))
{
    $email = $_POST['emailsignup'];
    $username = $_POST['usernamesignup'];
    $password = $_POST['passwordsignup'];
    $sql ="INSERT INTO users (email,username, password) VALUES ('$email', $username','$password')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($result) {
        echo "you have registered successfully";
    }
    else {
        echo "there was a problem";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Please confirm your information";
}

?>
```

Here's html code

```
<div id="register" class="animate form">
<form  action="signup_ac.php" autocomplete="on" method="POST"> 
<h1> Sign up </h1> 
<p> 
<label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
<input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required type="text"   placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
</p>
<p> 
<label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
<input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required type="email"   placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/> 
</p>
<p> 
<label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
<input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
</p>
<p> 
<label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your   password </label>
<input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required  type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
</p>
<p class="signin button">
<input type="submit" value="Sign up"/> 
                            </p>
                            <p class="change_link">  
                                Already a member ?
                                <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                       </div>
```

I have made a  simple registration form to test if its working.But when I try to open registration.php it only displays `please confirm your information`.there are two page for html registration.php and for php signup_ac.php. I do not understand why.If the problem is with my php then it should display the form I think .

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability...

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for quite some time.  Please have a look at MySQLi: http://www.php.net/mysqli or PDO MySQL: http://php.net/pdo_mysql to help you be safe against SQL injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to learn to debug your code:

```
if [...snip...] $POST_['passwordsignup_confirm'])){
                 ^^^^^--- dyslexic moment?
```

Comment: I have seen that just now and edited it but it still displays the same.i am kind of lost now.

Comment: so this is where you need to start learning how to debug. Start checking your inputs to the script. Are all of those $_POST values you're tryign to access actually there? maybe you've got a typo in your html form.